# No module named six

Tags: django, six-python

After installing `transifex` and ./manage.py the following error shows up:

```
Error: No modules named six.
```

Python Six is installed in the virtualenv (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) 
Django Version is 1.4

Any help would be great! 
thx & best regards
Michael

Comment: Are you sure you're in your virtual environment when you get the error. Plus, what task did you use?

Comment: Can you try opening a Python shell in the virtualenv, and running `import six` ?

Comment: Could it be that something is attempting to import `django.utils.six`, but it is only present in Django >= 1.5?

Comment: already done. if i open the shell there is the correct link to six -><module 'six' from '/root/txenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packagespy2.7.egg/six.pyc'>

Comment: @J. Ghyllebert: yes, in the virtenv i try to initialy start the transifex server with ./manage.py txcreatedirs

Comment: @jim: that no option, in django 1.5 the verify_exists parameter is deprecated. transifex won't work without it ;(

Comment: In case six is stored under the wrong Python version, see my
[kludge][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859356/error-no-module-named-six

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`django.utils.six` is added in Django 1.4.2, see

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/python3/#philosophy

Comment: hi, thanks but this isn't working. just found, that transifex is only working with django 1.3.1. so i installed django 1.3.1, but the same error. also "import six" in the python shell has no effect...

Comment: can you post traceback, ie ``./manage.py validate --traceback``

Comment: hi. same error, it just says: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transifex-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/transifex# ./manage.py validate --traceback
Error: cannot import name six

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError django_filters: cannot import name six

Comment: Traceback shows that ``django_filters`` raises exception.

Django-filters requires Django 1.4.5+, maybe you can try to install some older version

Comment: sir, you are the man of the week ;). with an olde version of django-filters (0.5.1) it is working!. thank you

Comment: Glad it helped. Traceback can help you to identify where the problem arises.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem. Seems like the dependencies in the transifex package are not listed correctly (it depends on Django == 1.3.1 and django-filter >= 0.1, but django-filter 0.6 depends on Django >= 1.4.5).

I solved by installing an older version of django-filter (0.5.4), NOT by using the package provided in pypi (seems that on pypi there are only 0.6 and 0.1 versions), but directly by downloading the release 0.5.4 from here:

https://github.com/alex/django-filter/releases

and then installing with the usual:

python setup.py install

Comment: For the record: these are all transifex dependencies I've to manually install (after uninstalling the versions automatically installed by pip) because those installed automatically where not correct:

django-filter==0.5.4
django-haystack==1.2
django-piston==0.2.2

Answer (score -4):

This should solve your problem:

```
$ easy_install six
```