# Error No module named six

Tags: python

I am new to Python/OpenCV.

I have the code below run in Python. But I got an error as shown below.

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

I followed what is being suggested in this post: [ImportError: No module named six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967428/importerror-no-module-named-six)

I have downloaded six-1.8.0.tar.gz and unzip the file.  I am wondering of is the next thing to do?  I tried to run the six.py but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to download the `tar.gz` file. Instead run this at the command line (note, not the Python command line):

`pip install six`

And if that doesn't work, try:

`easy_install six`

Comment: Tried this one, but got an error.  'pip' is not recognized .... same with 'easy_install'

Comment: Here are directions to install pip, you can try them out: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: I have used cmd. the error is 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I have tried that link, and I am very confused.  I tried the command and got an error.

Comment: I was able to successfully installed six but when I tried to run again "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt" I got the same error "import six
ImportError: No module named six"

Comment: I have this same exact issue, and even though six seems to be installed everywhere, I get the import error. Was this problem fixed at all?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem (No module named six) when I tried to import `nltk` and to type `easy_install six` in cmd (Windows), it installed `six` for me.

And I imported `nltk` successfully.