# No module named six - even though six is installed

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pip

I'm trying to use matplotlib but I'm getting this error saying "No Module named six". I read previous answers and installed six using pip and also tried pip install six --upgrade. But nothing worked. What could be wrong?

EDIT:

The TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Users\Akshay\Documents\Internship.py", line 290, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

And sorry I'm unfamiliar with the which command. I'm using Python 2.7, and the latest pip.

Comment: Please include the full python stack trace for your ImportError. Also include the output of `which pip` and `which python`.

Comment: Do I type "which pip" in the Command prompt?
It shows that "which" is not an internal or external command

Comment: You're on Windows. `which` is a `*nix` command; it won't work for you.

Comment: Have you run `python` on the command line, and then in the Python prompt, typed `>>> import six`? If that doesn't work, `pip` installed `six` in a weird way, or rather, `python` and `pip` are unrelated (which is what @cel was hinting at).

Comment: SO suggests that `where` on windows is somewhat equivalent to `which`, you could try that instead. But I would see first if `python -m pip install six` fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Before I did the -m command import six did nothing, but after I ran the -m command it worked!
What did -m do?
Also post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Your pip binary did not belong to the python interpreter you are currently using. So using `pip install six` installed the package for the wrong interpreter. `python -m pip install six` is a neat hack to make sure that you call the right `pip`

Comment: In case six is stored under the wrong Python version, see my
[kludge][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859356/error-no-module-named-six